# Xcode manipulation of period in product name and product id

Tags: ios, xcode, in-app-purchase

When creating an iOS In App Purchase project, Xcode manipulates the product name changing '.' to '-'. The resulting product id in the info-plist is an illegal product identifier as only A-Z,a-z,0-9,_,. are allowed in iTunes Connect.

What process is causing Xcode to change the '.' in the product name, e.g., title.11, to a '-' (hyphen), e.g., title-11? Is there anyway to prevent it?

Thanks!

Comment: Dude it impossible something can happen like this, i am also using the InAppPurchase and while requesting the products i am not facing this kind of an issue. Can you share the piece of code which you have implemented?

Comment: @Harsh - Code won't explain and I cannot post images. Create an IAP and enter a product name like "foo.bar". Complete the creation of the project and look at the Product Id field in the info.plist, it will show "foo-bar". You can "see" a similar effect in the project create dialog for the bundle id. My concern is is for the product id, though. BTW Xcode 6.3.2.